# Are there references of relations between logical functions and polynomials?

Tags: logic, reference-request

I would appreciate any recommendations for references of relations between logical functions and polynomials.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! What do you mean by "logical functions"? Do you mean [Boolean functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function)?

Comment: Are you familiar with the translation between Boolean algebras and [Boolean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring#Relation_to_Boolean_algebras)?

Comment: Yes, I mean Boolean functions.

Comment: No, I am not familiar with the translation

Comment: Probably you will be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhegalkin_polynomial

Answer (score 2):

Any function $\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ can be represented as a polynomial in $\Bbb{F}_2[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and two polynomials $f,g$ give the same function iff $f-g = \sum_{j=1}^n (x_j^2-x_j) h_j$ for some polynomials $h_j$